# How to dynamically declare shape of an Array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am working with an API where I need to provide a `Object[]`, `Object[][]`, `Object[][][]`... you get the idea.

Assume `setFoo` requires an `Object[]`, this is how I get it to work:

```
Object hello = "Hello";
Object world = "world";

final List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
objects.add(hello);
objects.add(world);

// {"Hello", "world"}
item.setFoo(objects.toArray());
```

And this is how I make `Object[][]` requirement work, so that I can call `setBar`..

```
Object hello = "Hello";
Object world = "world";

// We now we need to stuff these into an Array of Arrays as in: {{Hello},{world}}
final List<Object> helloList = new ArrayList<>();
helloList.add(hello);

final List<Object> worldList = new ArrayList<>();
worldList.add(world);

final List<List<Object>> surroundingList = new ArrayList<>();
surroundingList.add(helloList);
surroundingList.add(worldList);

final Object[][] objects = new Object[surroundingList.size()][1];
for (int i = 0; i < surroundingList.size(); i++) {
    objects[i] = surroundingList.get(i).toArray();
}

item.setBar(objects);
```

The problem is, I am not able to figure out how to create the Object[][][] dynamically.. Is there a way to do this in Java? If I can make this `final Object[][] objects = new Object[surroundingList.size()][1];` dynamic I should be in good hands.

Comment: I guess it is not possible. Because we need to create the dimensions first, assignment is next. But your need is dimensions should be dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this with static code.  The Java syntax and (compile time) type system doesn't support the declaration or construction of arrays with indefinite dimensions.

You can create arrays with arbitrary dimensions using reflection; e.g.

```
int nosDimensions = 2;
Class<MyClass> clazz = MyClass.class;
Object array = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz, nosDimensions);

MyClass[][] typedArray = (MyClass[][]) array;  // just to show we can do it ...
```

But the problem is that if you go down the path, you are liable to end up:

- doing lots of casting to types with definite dimensions (see `typedArray` above), and / or
- doing operations on the arrays using messy reflective code.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need.

Comment: Yea ... but I hope you don't do this.  It you need indefinite dimensioned arrays, you are probably better off implementing your own multidimensional array class.  IMO.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure, you seem to cast statically. How do you populate this array dynamically? How do you invoke `array[i][j]` or `array[i][j][k]` ? But it is still a good start for me, ty.

Comment: "How do you populate this array dynamically?"  Clunky reflection; e.g. calls to `Array.set(array, index, value)` or similar (depending on the array's base type).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time and sharing your knowledge. Will be very helpful for me.

Comment: "array[i][j]" - would be `Array.get(Array.get(array, i), j)` ... and so on, until your brain hurts and your fingers are bleeding.

Comment: `Array.get(Array.get(array, i), j)` This is still static, you still need to know the dimension, isnt it? Or am I missing smth? I need something like: Array.set(List.. int) so I can pass arbitarary number of integers to point..

Comment: Your example was static.  If you are trying to perform operations using an indefinite number of indexes, you use a loop and iterate the dimensions.   Is your brain starting to hurt yet?   (And no, there is no `Array.set(int... indices)`  !!)